# Symfony2 Doctrine ManyToOne dependents on owner

Tags: orm, doctrine

I have a User object with name and surname. User can be set as a ghost. If User is ghost I want to give other Users possibility to name him as they like.

```
|User   |   |Representation|
|-------|   |--------------|
|ID     |   |owner         |
|isGhost|   |ghost         |
|name   |   |name          |
|surname|   |surname       |
```

`owner` and `ghost` reffers to `User`
`owner` is always a logged in User

What I want to achieve is - if User isn't ghost - (as owner) I want to see `User.name` and `User.surname` but if User is ghost - (as owner) I want to see `Representation.name` and `Representaion.surname`.

How to make a mapping for that kind of situation to be most effective?

**EDIT:**
What else - I have a Relation object with reference to User and in Relation using `getUser()` I'd like to see proper name and surname depending if User is ghost.

Maybe use ArrayCollection instead of additional table and save all representations in ghost User? Predicted max representation per ghost User is about 5-10. Not much.

Answer (score 0):

You should proceed like you designed your two tables: make a `OneToMany` relation bw User and Representation on ghost, and another `OneToMany` relation bw User and Owner.

Make sure the owning side is User as you don't want to load each time the Representation objects when you query your user.

Then, do only a `->getRepresentations()` that'll fetch the associated representations for an user when necessary, eg: when true === isGhost;

Question is, if an User is ghost and do not have a Representation for an owner, what do you display?

You could do this function:

```
public function getUsername($ownerRepresentation = false)
{

    // user is ghost mode, but we do not have an owner for its representation
    if ($this->isGhost && false === $ownerRepresentation) {
        return '~';
    }

    // user is ghost, and we have provided an owner to search for his representation
    if ($this->isGhost && false !== $ownerRepresentation) {
        $representations = $this->getRepresentations();

        foreach ($representations as $representation) {
            if ($representation->getOwner()->getId() === $ownerRepresentation->getId()) {
                return $representation->getName() . ' ' . $representation->getSurname();
            }
        }

        // no representation found for this owner
        return '~';
    }

    // user is no ghost, we can freely display his real name
    return $this->getName() . ' ' . $this->getSurname();
}
```